# How to build a wrapper pytest plugin?

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-html

I want to wrap the pytest-html plugin in the following way:

1. Add an option X
2. Given the option X, delete data from the report

I was able to add the option with implementing the `pytest_addoption(parser)` function, but got stuck on the 2nd thing...

What I was able to do is this: implement a hook frmo pytest-html. However, I have to access my option X, in order to do what to do. The problem is, pytest-html's hook does not give the "request" object as a param, so I can't access the option value...

Can I have additional args for a hook? or something like this?

Comment: Do you really need it? Why not `report.config.getoption("myoption")`? The only hook where the report object is not available is `pytest_html_results_table_header`, but you can use any of the other four hooks instead.

Comment: Thanks! This is actually the way I tried first, but report is a TestReport object, and does not have "config" member. Only HTMLReport has "config"...

Comment: Indeed, you're right - let me add an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach additional data to the report object, for example via a custom wrapper around the `pytest_runtest_makereport` hook:

```
@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    outcome = yield
    report = outcome.get_result()
    report.config = item.config
```

Now the `config` object will be accessible via `report.config` in all reporting hooks, including the ones of `pytest-html`:

```
def pytest_html_report_title(report):
    """ Called before adding the title to the report """
    assert report.config is not None
```

Comment: And this way is better than declaring a global and assigning value to it inside `pytest_configure()`?

Comment: You mean module globals? I would avoid that - first, `pytest` discourages this, second, you can't possibly think of all implications a global might cause; think of running the tests in parallel via `xdist` and stuff.