# Add browser version to pytest-html report

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, pytest, pytest-html

I get browser version from command line argument but can't add it to report :(

conftest.py:

```
import pytest


def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--browser-version")

def pytest_html_report_title(report):
    report.title = "need browser version string here"
```

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/61497447/2650249, from there you can access the option via `report.config.getoption("--browser-version")`.

Comment: @hoefling thanks a lot!

    `report.title = report.config.getoption("--browser-version")`

solved my problem